# Add ListBox values toTextBox on Button click in ASP.Net did not work correctly

Tags: asp.net

I have a one list box and one text box, i want to add list box value to text box on Button Click , but its not working correctly, can you please help me ,i can add the item  for text box but cant add more item for text box (MultiSelect)Thanks in advance

**TextBox**

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesignName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="250px" ></asp:TextBox>
 </div>
```

**listBox**

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <asp:ListBox ID="lstValue" runat="server" CssClass="content" Rows="5" ValidationGroup="save"
               Width="250" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lstValues_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
</div>
```

**Add Button**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Add" ValidationGroup="add"
         Width="70" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
```

**CodeBehind**

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if(txtDesignName.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
    //{
    //    return; 
    //}
    //else
    //{
        lstValue.Items.Add(txtDesignName.Text);
    //}
}
```

**lstValues_SelectedIndexChanged**

```
protected void lstValues_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtQlt.Text = lstValue.SelectedItem.ToString();  
        }
```

Comment: are you trying to add items to the lists box or the textbox ? lstValue.Items.Add(txtDesignName.Text); will add items to the listbox.Mybe you got it mixed up

Comment: i want to  add  List box items to text box,

Comment: Is it multi-select list box?

Comment: @codeninja.sj     Sir, its a Multi-Select list box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question, you have asked and the code you have shown are both representing different purposes. So, I provided the two options; choose whatever you want.

To display all selected list box-items to your text-box

```
protected void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //create display button to do this process
{
  string selectedItems = string.Empty;
  string separator = ",";
  foreach (int i in lstValue.GetSelectedIndices())
  {
   selectedItems += lstValue.Items[i] + separator;
  }
  txtDesignName.Text = selectedItems.Trim(',');
}
```

To add text-box value to list-box items

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (txtDesignName.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
  {
    lstValue.Items.Add(new ListItem(txtDesignName.Text));
    txtDesignName.Text = string.Empty; //reset the text-box value
  }
}
```

Comment: Code is working, but cant add multi select value, im add the value its work but im add another value its working, always replace the  add 1st value for it, example List Box Value (AA),(BB) , Firstly add the AA , secondly add BB , its not see AA , i want to Display AA BB

Comment: I guess, You may reset the list box items in the page_load event. Can you show your full code?

Comment: Sir , I Do it, Its Working now, Thanks For the help ) its working now